# Python Pyrebase Config

Tags: python, firebase-storage, pyrebase

When I'm trying to run my code:

```
import pyrebase

    firebaseConfig = {
        "apiKey": "xxxxxx",
        "authDomain": "xxxxxx",
        "projectId": "xxxxxx",
        "storageBucket": "xxxxxxx",
        "serviceAccount": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
    
    firebase_storage = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
    storage = firebase_storage.storage()
    
    storage.child("uploads").put("xxxxxxx")
```

I'm getting an error:

> self.database_url = config["databaseURL"]
>
> KeyError: 'databaseURL'

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: Add a key-value to your `firebaseConfig` with `key=databaseURL` and `value=your_database_url`. see [this](https://dev.to/gogamic/introduction-to-pyrebase-database-2mif) example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a new Firebase project it no longer creates a Realtime Database by default. And that also means that the `databaseURL` key is no longer included in the configuration snippet by default.

It looks like Pyrebase still requires this key to exist though, which is why you get an error.

Two things to try (in this order):

1. Just add a key with no value, or a dummy value to the firebaseConfig:

   ```
   firebaseConfig = {
       "apiKey": "xxxxxx",
       "authDomain": "xxxxxx",
       "databaseURL": "xxxxxx",
       "projectId": "xxxxxx",
       "storageBucket": "xxxxxxx",
       "serviceAccount": "xxxxxxxxx"
   }
   ```
2. If the above doesn't work, you can create a Realtime Database in the Firebase console, and get the new config snippet from there.

I also filed an [issue](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/370) against Pyrebase to no longer require this key, which is what all official Firebase SDKs have been updated to do.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```py
"databaseURL" : ""
```

in **firebaseConfig** (if you are not using database).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `databaseURL` key to your configurations.
Please take a look at this answer:
[KeyError: 'databaseURL' while Firebase Authentication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965299/keyerror-databaseurl-while-firebase-authentication-in-python/69357824#69357824)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyrebase

config ={

    "apiKey": "*********",
    "authDomain": "***-****.firebaseapp.com",
    "projectId": "****-*****",
    "storageBucket": "****-***.appspot.com",
    "messagingSenderId": "********",
    "appId": "1:********:web:*********",
    "measurementId": "G-*********",
    "databaseURL" : ""

}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage = firebase.storage()

storage.child("download1.png").put("download.png")
```

> Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```