# Python with FireBase

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

I really need help and am not sure why my code is not executing. I tried everything by reading different solution and there was no answer.
so, I created a project with Firebase. As usual, i set up a config, and then initialized my firebase, and initialized my auth.
After that, i wrote another line to create user_Credentials email with password. For some reason my python is not executing and I really dunno why.

Here is my code

```
 # Initializing firebase 
fireBase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
authen = fireBase.auth()

# testing 
email = "testing@gmail.com"
password = "123456"

authen.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kin/Desktop/GitHubRepo/project/client/src/sign_up/authentication.py", line 15, in <module>
    fireBase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 28, in initialize_app
    return Firebase(config)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.database_url = config["databaseURL"]
KeyError: 'databaseURL'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not defined a value for `"databaseURL"` in your `firebaseConfig`.

Comment: I already had my config set up correctly

Comment: Please share the code you are using to open/parse your config file. You are showing an image of a javascript variable.

Comment: i found out an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873454/python-pyrebase-config/65873526#65873526

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pyrebase still requires this key to exist though, which is why you get an error.

You can do this two things for now....

> 1 - Just add a key with no value, or a dummy value

---

```
API_KEY = {
    'apiKey': "##############################",
    'authDomain': "********************",
    'projectId': "&&&&&&&&&&&",
    'storageBucket': "************",
    'messagingSenderId': "*************",
    'appId': "***************",
    'measurementId': "************",
    'databaseURL': ""
}
```

> 2 - Add the databaseURL from Your firebase account [from here](https://%20Firebase%20-%20Realtime%20Database%20Ad%C2%B7%20https://firebase.google.com/firebase/database)

```
API_KEY = {
        'apiKey': "##############################",
        'authDomain': "********************",
        'projectId': "&&&&&&&&&&&",
        'storageBucket': "************",
        'messagingSenderId': "*************",
        'appId': "***************",
        'measurementId': "************",
        'databaseURL': "link of your databaseURL"
}
```

well there was an [issue](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/370) already open at [Pyrebase](https://github.com/Mr-Sunglasses/Pyrebase4) which target to this problem, fell free to solve this issue.